# Disable Chrome minimum font-size 10px

Tags: google-chrome, font-size

I got some text with

```
font-size:9px
```

But it is displaying correctly in Safari and Firefox but not with Mac/Chrome (V32).
Left is chrome [bad] / Right is Safari [correct]

[image]

I can see in the code inspector that my font is 9px but chrome switch to 10px :

[image]

I heard about the minimum font size in chrome and tried to disable the auto adjustment by following style but did not work.
Any idea?

```
* {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible to circumvent the user's preferences regarding minimum font size. I also don't think it's _right_ to try and circumvent the user's preferences regarding minimum font size.

Comment: It is not a user's preference, I never put a minimum font size in my Chrome. This is Chrome's rules, because Safari and Firefox do not have this problem.

Comment: Check out Chrome's settings, just in case. (menu) -> Settings -> Show Advanced Settings -> Web Content -> Customize Fonts -> Minimum Font Size.

Comment: Or if you like, Paramêtres -> Afficher les paramètres avancés… -> Personnaliser les polices -> Taille de police minimale.

Comment: OK my Chrome minimum font-size is 10px I see. I agree I should not try to circumvent user's preference but here it is not users pref, it is Chrome default values, I never asked 10px for minimum font-size. And for the discussion, firefox and safari do not have that limit...

Comment: That's right, with Firefox you can set the minimum size to "none"; with Chrome you can only go as low as 6. I hadn't realised that to be honest, but it is something you'll have to live with.

Answer (score 11):

i can only tell WHY it's not working but this might help you to go looking for a different way to solve your problem.

from chrome version 28.0.1500.11 chrome doesn't support -webkit-text-size-adjust anymore. (changelist is here: http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/145168). and safari follows along. on newer mac os versions text-size-adjust is already gone too.

I have problems with it as well, since i've built a whole website on rem units to make it not only responsive but totally flexible. this worked pretty nice but all of a sudden everything is huge now. i'm working hard on a solution for this, but if anyone has an idea i didn't think of i'd appreciate that very much.

as soon as i find a solution i'll come back to let you know.

Comment: How did you solve the problem? I ran into the exact same thing after styling a website with all its containers with rem in order to be able to adjust the scaling by myself later.