# Calculated value from rems with html font size set to 6.25% in Chrome six times bigger then in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I set the html font size to 6.25% so that 1px = 1rem. My site works perfectly in firefox but when I open it in chrome everything except the font size is too big. The width, height, padding anything set in rem is 6 times bigger.

Please take a look at the provided [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zsyruqx0/2/)  or the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <style>
      html {font-size: 6.25%;}
      div {
        padding: 10rem;
        width: 50rem;
        height: 50rem;
        background-color: chocolate;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="block"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you open it in firefox you get [this which is expected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ismey.png)

However if you open the code in chrome [you get this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ypLf.png)

As you can see the chrome version is 6 time bigger resulting in the width and height being 300px instead of 50px. What is causing this and how do I solve the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: you are having the min font-size that is not allowing you to have less than 6px ... https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/_iUJxIo68d0

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302069/disable-chrome-minimum-font-size-10px

Comment: oh no you mean I should have listened and set my font-size to 62.5% instead of 6.25% so that my minimum is 10px and then it will work?

Comment: I would say yes, keep the value of font-size bigger to avoid issue, then use smaller value with padding/height/width where there is no minimum restriction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google gets in the way once again (for W10 version 69.0.3497.100 (Official build) (64-bits)):

Check Chrome Settings and adjust the minimum font-size for the browser. With the slider at its minimum you will see a tiny example text at, and here it comes, 6px in size. Inspect that text and you will see its size 'computed' at 6px from internal Chrome css [text_defaults_md.css](http://chrome://resources/css/text_defaults_md.css) 81.25% body font-size.

It looks like Chrome simply uses this minimum value in all cases for HTML `:root` unless you change `:root.font-size` **or** `html.font-size` to some hardcoded value in your HTML document (in your case 1px). Percentages (relative values) will not work.

Whether this has been done by choice, a bug or some programmers' logic cannot be said, however, it does not seem standard to me.

The only option (workaround) is to change the div font-size to 1px and use em instead of rem.

Comment: it's by design because *logically* we don't need to have a text with 1px font-size so they setup the minimal readable font-size or something like this ... there is not spec for this of course, it's browser specific

Comment: Admitted, I would not construct a colored block like the above either, but font-size 0 should be possible (whether logical or not). Accepting your sentiment, though.